# How do i extract them && How do i remove them

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Both of my problems remain on arrays (i'm a noob and i'm trying to learn, sorry ). So...

//Prob_1
I want to extract only the info i need from every test. I'm doing this without using an object.

//Prob_2
I'm trying to delete all the trash characters to store the other ones in a new var, to show the message

P.S: i'm just trying stuff to see how to do it

```
//Pob_1

const hell = ['test1: Oh god', 'test2: Plz god', 'test3: Plz god no'];

let extractedChar = [];

extractedChar = (databaseEntry[1].Name + databaseEntry[2].Rank + databaseEntry[0].Faction);

console.log(extractedChar);

//Prob_2

const heavenAndHell = [['☆','S','a','☆','☆','t'],
                       ['a','☆','n','☆','H','e'],
                       ['l','p','☆','s','☆','y'],
                       ['o','☆','u','x','☆','D']];

function losingIt(){
  for (let i = 0; i < heavenAndHell ; i++){
    for (let x = 0; x < heavenAndHell [i].length; x++){

      var heaven = '☆';

      if (heaven = '☆'){
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Better explanation could help. One thing I can tell you for sure is that `if (heaven = '☆'){` should most likely be `if (heaven == '☆'){`. First is value assignment when second is the comparison

Answer (score 0):

Prob 1 :

```js
const hell = ['test1: Oh god', 'test2: Plz god', 'test3: Plz god no'];

/* with reduce */

const res = hell.reduce((all, curr) => {
  const obj = curr.split(":");
  all.push({
    [obj[0]]: obj[1]
  });
  return all;
}, [])

/* with map */

const res2 = hell.map(el => ({
  [el.split(":")[0]]: el.split(":")[1]
}))

console.log(res2);
```

Prob 2 :

```js
const heavenAndHell = [
  ['☆', 'S', 'a', '☆', '☆', 't'],
  ['a', '☆', 'n', '☆', 'H', 'e'],
  ['l', 'p', '☆', 's', '☆', 'y'],
  ['o', '☆', 'u', 'x', '☆', 'D']
];

/* first solution*/

var word = "";

heavenAndHell.map(el => {
  el.map(el => {
    if (el.match(/[a-z_A-Z]/i))
      word += el;
  })
})

console.log(word);

/* seconde solution */
const res = heavenAndHell.flat().filter((el) => el.match(/[a-z_A-Z]/i)).join("");

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1 - `map` it to remove the unwanted characters with `split`:

```js
const hell = ['test1: Oh god', 'test2: Plz god', 'test3: Plz god no'];

const words = hell.map(s => s.split(": ")[1]);

console.log(words);
```

---

Problem 2 - again, `map` over the array unwanted characters, but test them with a regex instead, and perform some array operations to remove empty arrays elements and remove the multidimensional array:

```js
const heavenAndHell = [
  ['☆', 'S', 'a', '☆', '☆', 't'],
  ['a', '☆', 'n', '☆', 'H', 'e'],
  ['l', 'p', '☆', 's', '☆', 'y'],
  ['o', '☆', 'u', 'x', '☆', 'D']
];

const words = heavenAndHell.map(a => a.map(e => e.match(/[A-Za-z]/))).flat(2).filter(Boolean).join("");

console.log(words);
```